# unknown bug causing program to return weird symbols

Tags: c++

I wrote a very basic program to separate vowels from a input string.
The program is separating vowels but also returning weird symbols/letters!

I seriously can't find why it is happening! help!

output >>

> aoeeo x ╘E⌡óì

It generates different letters(?) everytime i run it!

code >>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string input = "stackoverflow";
  vector<char>  vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
  vector<char> result;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < input.size() ; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < vowels.size(); j++){
      if(input[i] == vowels[j]){
      result.push_back(input[i]);
      }
    }
      if (input[i] == 'u' || input[i] == 'e') {
        result.push_back(input[i]);
      }
  }

  for(int i = 0 ; i < input.size() ; i++){
    cout << result[i];
  }

  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: There are only four vowels in "stackoverflow", none of which are 'u' or 'e', so `result` has size 4 before printing.   However, the last loop uses `input.size()` to control a loop printing elements of `result`, so prints 13 characters of a vector with four characters.   That gives undefined behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read from non-alocated memory. The vowels are stored in result vector which is smaller than input vector. Change your printing loop into:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < result.size() ; i++){
cout << result[i];
```

Comment: note: this problem could be avoided with `for (auto ch : result) cout << ch;`